# Ability to loop through contents of files

Tags: gitlab, terraform, terraform-template-file

I have the following code, the goal is for the content of each yaml file specified to be populated in a given repository, however only the filename is populated not the content.

```
 main.tf
 resource "git_repository_file" "myresource" {
   for_each = toset(local.filecontents)
   project = var.project-name
   filepath = var.filepath
   content = each.value
 }

 locals.tf {
 filecontents = fileset(path.module, "*.yaml")
 }

 directory in question has 5 yaml files
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually read in the file, using [file](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/file):

```
 resource "git_repository_file" "myresource" {
   for_each = toset(local.filecontents)
   project = var.project-name
   filepath = var.filepath
   content = file(each.value)
 }
```